# Playwright configuration to imitate my original browser actions

Tags: javascript, chromium, playwright, browser-automation

I'm trying to write a simple bot using Playwright for a browser game. Game has one repetitive action (button clicking) which I would like to avoid. My idea is to be able to play the game on my original browser and use Playwright to perform that repetitive action. What I want to achieve is to configure Playwright so that it would seem that all actions were performed from my browser.

I'm setting UserAgent to my user agent.
I'm not setting proxy, so all the request will come from my IP address.
I'm setting webdriver value to undefined (maybe I should set it to false?)

This is the code that I'm using to open browser:

```js
const browserDetails = await chromium.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    setBrowser(browserDetails);

    const contextDetails = await browser.newContext({
      userAgent: myUserAgent,
    });
    setContext(contextDetails);

    await context.addInitScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");

    const pageDetails = await context.newPage();
    setPage(pageDetails);
    await page.goto(loginUrl);

    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="name"]', 'input[name="password"]', 'button[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitForTimeout(randomWaitTimeSeconds1_2());
    await page.type('input[name="name"]', username, { delay: 50 });
    await page.type('input[name="password"]', password, { delay: 50 });
    await page.waitForTimeout(randomWaitTimeSeconds1_2());
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
```

And this is the code that I'm using for button clicking:

```js
  await page.waitForTimeout(randomWaitTimeSeconds1_2());
  const btnNav = 'span.name:has-text("text")';
  await page.waitForSelector(btnNav);
  const span = await page.$(btnNav);

  logger.info(`going to the page`);
  await page.click(span);

  logger.info(`looking for a start button`);
  await page.waitForTimeout(randomWaitTimeSeconds1_2());
  const startBtnSelector = 'button.start';
  await page.waitForSelector(startBtnSelector)
  const startBtn = await page.$(startBtnSelector);

  await page.click(startBtn);

  // then it will click a button to go to "neutral" page
  // wait for 10-15minutes with page.waitForTimeout()
  // after that will check if user is logged in (according to the navigators)
  // will log in if required
  // click required buttons again
  // action repeated again

  // there will be a function which from time to time will close browser and excecute 
  // login and proceed with button clicking
```

Is current configuration enough to hide that I'm using Playwright and is it enough to set userAgent value to imitate that I'm using Chrome instead of Playwright? I'm not entirely sure how anti-bot detection works (I know I should imitate human-like behaviour, but beside all that..)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use Playwright rather than a userscript? What's the site, and what specific problem are you having here? Most of the questions are broad and open-ended, but there should be one specific question per post.

Comment: @ggorlen , specific question would be is current configuration enough to hide that I'm using Playwright and is it enough to set userAgent value to imitate that I'm using Chrome instead of Playwright? I'm using Playwright because I'm a bit familiar with it and not with userscript. My previous bot was detected and I think I didn't hide that I was using automated browser.

Answer (score 1):

By trying many times with the same IP could be a reason for the anti-bot system to detect non-human behavior. Try to rotate your IP.

Regarding the user-agent, as long as you use a real one you are fine.  [Here you can find real user agents to use in your Playwright](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list)

After reading the Playwright documentation I found some reasons why maybe your user-agent is not used in all the contexts and pages in Playwright.

1. Apply user agent to playwright/test

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

test.use({ userAgent: myUserAgent });
```

2. Use user_agent when creating new pages:

```
const pageDetails = await context.newPage(user_agent=myUserAgent);
```

Let me know if any of these suggestions helped you, and good luck :)